# Add event screen is not opening in iOS

Tags: ios, ekevent, ekeventstore, ekcalendar

In my iOS app I want to create event in calendar and I've found code but the code directly creates an event instead of opening Add event screen. I want to allow user to set reminder through add event screen.

**My Code is Below :**

```
EKEventStore *es = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
EKAuthorizationStatus authorizationStatus = [EKEventStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent];
BOOL needsToRequestAccessToEventStore = (authorizationStatus == EKAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined);

if (needsToRequestAccessToEventStore) {
    [es requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (granted) {
            EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:es];
            event.title = @"Event Title";
            event.startDate = [NSDate date]; // today
            event.endDate = [event.startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60];  // Duration 1 hr
            [event setCalendar:[es defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
            NSError *err = nil;
            [es saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];
              NSLog(@"Error : %@", err);
        } else {
            // Denied
        }
    }];
} else {
    BOOL granted = (authorizationStatus == EKAuthorizationStatusAuthorized);
    if (granted) {
        EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:es];
        event.title = @"Event Title";
        event.startDate = [NSDate date]; // today
        event.endDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60];  // Duration 1 hr
        [event setCalendar:[es defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
        NSError *err = nil;
        [es saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];
        NSLog(@"Error : %@", err);
    } else {
        // Denied
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based in the [EKEventStore](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/ReadingAndWritingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004775-SW1) documentation, the method: `[es saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];` is saving the event. Your code is working correctly and this code should not open the "Add event screen" as you are expecting.